# Subdomain Routing in React and React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, subdomain

I have 3 types of users and we want to maintain the same code base for the project instead of having 3-4 code bases when most views are just subjective to the kind of users.

> Admin > admin.example.com
>
> Moderator > moderator.example.com
>
> Brands > brands.example.com

My structure of the React App

```
src
-BaseRoutes.js <--- Should handle by subdomain logic
- modules
-- admin
---- AdminRoutes.js <---- handles all Admin route logic
---- components
---- pages
-- moderator
---- ModeratorRoutes.js <---- handles all Moderator route logic
---- components
---- pages
-- brands
---- BrandsRoutes.js <---- handles all Brands route logic
---- components
---- pages
- components
- pages
```

Each type of user will have its own authentication to allow access to inner routes. I found a function to split the domain and do the routing using the following:

```
let host = window.location.host;
let protocol = window.location.protocol;
let parts = host.split(".");
let subdomain = "";
// If we get more than 3 parts, then we have a subdomain
// INFO: This could be 4, if you have a co.uk TLD or something like that.
if (parts.length >= 3) {
  subdomain = parts[0];
  // Remove the subdomain from the parts list
  parts.splice(0, 1);
  // Set the location to the new url
  window.location = protocol + "//" + parts.join(".") + "/" + subdomain;
}
```

Is this the right way to handle subdomain based routing in React? I have never used a single code base for multiple user types. So confused about the right implementation.

Comment: What router are you using?. You should check out React Router, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Comment: @Joshua Am using the same. But didn't find any help on a subdomain for that.

Comment: This sounds like it's something that would not be handled by `client/react-router` but rather by your server that your SPA is served on. Assuming all three sub-domains serve the same `React` codebase I suggest you figure out what the subdomain is from the code you posted above and render different components conditionally, i.e. if it's `admin` show render only `admin`-specific routes/links/navigation, etc...

Comment: @goto1 you are right. Any  suggestions?

Comment: @HarshaMV I've implemented what you're trying to achieve once, but I don't have access to the codebase anymore to give you some examples. Create a global router i.e BaseRouter, then admin, moderator, etc should then have their own routers. More like a router with child routers. You can then add authentication to each route.

Comment: @Joshua was it stable? did you face any problems with routing this way? Anything I should be aware of?

Comment: @HashaMV no, I didn't face any issue. I'm not sure there's any other way it can be handled. But there could still be an optimal solution out there. Did my previous answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should check subdomain of current url and match it with specific user role, then in react router you could use that simple logic, in order to render only role specific routes:

```
<Router history={history}>
          {isAdmin &&
            <Route component={AdminViews} />
          }
          {isModerator &&
            <Route component={ModeratorViews} />
          }
...
          <Route path="/tnc" exact={true} component={CommmonRouteForAllRoles} />
</Router>
```

Where e.g. AdminViews could look like this:

```
export const AdminViews = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact={true} component={AdminHome} />
          <Route path="/other" exact={true} component={AdminOtherRoute} />
          <Route path="/sign-in" exact={true} component={AdminSignIn} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Comment: How do I get Users to login? Since all the three logins are different?

Comment: You can add /sign-in route for every single role, each pointing to different sign in component. Then admin.example.com/sign-in  will point to different component than moderator.example.com/sign-in. In that way you can still use the same logic transparently of the user role. E.g. if it's not authenticated, just push to /sign-in

Answer (score 1):

I guess your server should be able to achieve this e.g, you can create subdomains for admin and moderator while the user domain will be the base route, so if admin is to login, he goes to `admin.yourapp.com`, and moderator goes to `moderator.yourapp.com` and then handle auth logic, the view won't really be a problem if you use react-router then