# How do I create a subdomain in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm creating a website that will consist of two parts, one for customers and one for companies. I would like to give the company part its own subdomain, more presicley I want to give them a dashboard under dashboard.myapp.com like Stripe or Fauna. How would I go about doing this?

Should I split the app in two and have one for the dashboard.myapp.com domain and one for the [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) domain, or would it be sufficient to have them both in the same app and just check when a user is on the subdomain like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884567/subdomain-routing-in-react-and-react-router) answer?

Answer (score 0):

subdomains aren't created within react. You would need to create it with your Domain name registrar. You can then use react to route people to each domain after creation.

Comment: Would you say it's better to do it like that or to have two separate react applications under each domain?

Comment: That depends on how you want to configure your environment. I highly recommend you post this question with more information about your configuration/stack as it's out of scope for this current question.