# How do I achieve this 2 web addresses for one website. i.e. www.administrator.sitename.com and www.sitename.com?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I want to create a website where I want a normal web address for site visitors i.e. `www.sitename.com` and the administrator of the website should have a web address like `www.administrator.sitename.com`. How do I achieve this? Just to clear things out, site visitors do not have the feature to create their own accounts on the website. There is only one user that exists i.e. Administrator.

Any other suggestions for implementing this system are also appreciated. This system will be implemented using **the MERN stack** so, please provide references accordingly.

Comment: Well this depends on your DNS configuration more than it does your MERN stack. Give this a read: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/

Comment: would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884567/subdomain-routing-in-react-and-react-router ?

Comment: Would look at these articles too. Though @AkberIqbal the solution looks complicated in the reference you gave me, I would surely go through them once. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with **MERN Stack**. You basically need to do two things:

1. Create a subdomain. This can be done by visiting your domain registrar (like goDaddy or any website from which you've purchased your domain).
2. Host the admin panel on the subdomain.

So, let's say you have purchased example.com from GoDaddy. Now, login to your account on GoDaddy and add a subdomain `admin.example.com`. Follow the guide on how to add a subdomain for your registrar.

1. For GoDaddy, read [this](https://in.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-4080).
2. For Namecheap, read [this](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9776/2237/how-to-create-a-subdomain-for-my-domain/).

That's it. Now you need to host two different websites (one for users and another for admins) one on main domain and another on a subdomain of your choice.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out Amit. I would definitely go through all the references before starting with the project. So just to sum up everything, I would need to create 2 different node applications. One needs to be hosted on example.com for the normal users and the admin portal on admin.example.com?

Comment: No. You need to deploy two client side applications, one for admins, another for users. The server side application (nodejs application) doen't necessarily need to be different for the client and admin. The same API can serve two different clients.  I can show you few examples as well but you need to contact me for that. Details in my profile.

Comment: Okay, I got what you are saying Amit. If I have any further doubts related to this then would definitely contact you. Thanks :)